# File copy fails over Ubuntu Gateway using NAT

Tags: networking, iptables, scp, nat

I have managed to successfully set up NAT on my Ubuntu 14.04.4 machine so that my computer acts as a gateway for a computer connected on the internal  interface (`eth0`) to the external interface (`eth1`).

The main goal is not to give the internal computer internet access, but access to servers (subversion, etc) on the external interface.

NAT works and I can ping a server from the internal PC.

If I try to copy a file on the internal PC from a server on the external PC, the copy starts, but then stalls within a few seconds (speed starts at about 500KB/s then goes down to 0.0KB/s). My command to copy is straight forward:

```
$ scp user@server:/path/to/file . 
user@server's password:
file            1%  704KB 0.0KB/s - stalled -
```

The exact same copy command from my gateway PC completes with an avg of 12MB/s speed. The file is about 70MB.

How can I resolve this issue to make the copy complete, fast if possible?

---

*My setup:*

NAT is set up as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing)

1. The commands to set up the NAT on the gateway are:

   ```
   sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o eth1 -i eth0 -s 192.168.10.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
   sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
   sudo iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING
   sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
   ```
2. I did uncomment `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`
3. I did enable port forwarding using the following command:

   ```
   sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"
   ```

*PS*: I am using `scp` as a test and it shows the speed, same happens with `rsync`. In reality the file gets downloaded by an installer, possibly over http. Tested using `wget` and get exactly the same behaviour.

Comment: That should work. I wonder if you might have some previous attempt FORWARD rules that were never flushed? Try `sudo iptables -F FORWARD`, then add your rules. I'll post an answer with a different method to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to be very specific with interfaces and flow directions. Suggest this:

```
sudo iptables -F FORWARD
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o eth1 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: I have tried the commands given but unfortunately I get the same issue. PS: I have not yet added anything to make these changes persistent, thus after a restart I normally need to set the routing up again (since I am testing)

Comment: Time to use tcpdump (or wireshark, if you prefer) to observe what is going on at the packet level. Also use `sudo iptables -v -x -n -L` and `sudo iptables -t nat -v -x -n -L` to observe the iptables packet counters.